# How to align string lines in python?

Tags: python, string, alignment

There is an easy way to align string lines in python? (the line are saved in a list)

For example **s** is the list so convert-

```
s[0] = { part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 0 } } data { value = CCC } }

s[1] = { part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 88 } } data { value = C } }
```

To become:

```
s[0] = { part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 0  } } data { value = CCC } }

s[1] = { part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 88 } } data { value = C   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is very situationally specific though, it finds the largest number and sequence of Cs and uses `ljust()` to align:

```py
s = ['{ part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 0 } } data { value = CCC } }', \
    '{ part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 88 } } data { value = C } }' ]

maxlengthnums = 0
maxlengthletters = 0

for i in s:
    groups_s = re.search(r'({ part1{ c = FF000800  echo = )(\d+)( } } data { value = )(C+)(.*)', i)
    if len(groups_s.group(2)) > maxlengthnums:
        maxlengthnums = len(groups_s.group(2))
    if len(groups_s.group(4)) > maxlengthletters:
        maxlengthletters = len(groups_s.group(4))

print(maxlengthnums, maxlengthletters)

for i in range(len(s)):
    s[i] = re.sub(r'({ part1{ c = FF000800  echo = )(\d+)( } } data { value = )(C+)(.*)', lambda x: x.group(1) +\
    x.group(2).ljust(maxlengthnums, ' ') + x.group(3) + x.group(4).ljust(maxlengthletters, ' ') + x.group(5), s[i])

for i in s:
    print(i, '\n')

>>>

{ part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 0  } } data { value = CCC } } 

{ part1{ c = FF000800  echo = 88 } } data { value = C   } }
```